# Remover posições vazias de um array

Tags: php, javascript, array

Eu estou passando um `array` via `GET` para o PHP e depois envio para o lado do cliente (JavaScript). Quando eu o recebo ele fica dessa maneira:

```
m_prod = [5,,,,,,,,6,,,,,,];
```

Ou seja ele está incluindo um espaço nas posições que não contém um valor!
Como posso remover esses espaços no JavaScript?

```
<?php
    $m_prod = trim($_GET['m_prod']);
    print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> m_prod = \"$m_prod\"; </SCRIPT>");
?>
```

Comment: Queres apenas remover os espaços? Ou também reduzir o tamanho do array?

Comment: Bem, a principio gostaria de remover os espaços, pois ai o array ficaria só com  `m_prod = [5,6]; `

Comment: Então parece-me que já tens a resposta em baixo

Comment: @Alexandre pode explicar melhor de onde vem esse array? vem do PHP?

Comment: Sim o array vem do PHP!

Comment: @Alexandre então o interessante é ver o seu código PHP para resolver o problema na origem. Tem acesso ao PHP?

Comment: @Sergio já modifico o código para mostrar como chega meu php!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), da seguinte forma:

```
var m_prod = [5, , , , , , , , , ,6 , , , ];

var resultado = m_prod.filter(function(ele){
  return ele !== undefined;
});

console.log(resultado);  // [5,6]
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava! Obrigado @BrunoCalza

Comment: Assim @BrunoCalza, ele passa pelo filtro mas ainda continua mantendo as posições vazias! É como se ele não retornasse só os valores!

Comment: desculpe @Alexandre, não entendi. tenha em mente que o m_prod não será alterado.

Comment: Erro meu, em vez de utilizar o `undefined` utilizo o `""` assim retorna os campos que necessito!

Answer (score 8):

Se o problema vem do PHP acho que deve resolver no PHP.

Para filtrar uma array de elementos vazios:

```
$m_prod = array_filter($m_prod);
```

No caso de haver numeros dentro da array então temos de ter extra cuidado pois o `0` valida como false e é retirado da array. Assim pode fazer:

```
$m_prod = array_filter($m_prod, function($value) {
  return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
});
```

Para passar isso para o JavaScript pode renderizar assim:

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'm_prod = '.json_encode($m_prod);
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Dessa maneira também é tranquilo! Obrigado @Sergio

Comment: @Alexandre, Se você futuramente precisar criar uma API, sempre vai ter que sanitizar os resultados. Use o PHP para transitar as informações corretas.